# Android NavigationView vith rounded corners

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-navigationview, material-components-android

I am designing a **custom Drawer** on **Android**, it must have rounded corners in top and bottom, I am first customizing top side and I find the problem that the **background of the shape is not transparent**.

I have:
[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](https://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1568406523.png))</sub>

I need to build:
[image: design]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](https://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1568407937.png))</sub>

I would also like some help on how to round it on the bottom

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

side_nav_bar.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<corners android:radius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using the [`NavigationView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationView.md) in the Material Components library, you can apply a custom [**`ShapeAppearanceModel`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel) to the corner of the your `NavigationView`.

Something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.roundcorner);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
MaterialShapeDrawable navViewBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) navigationView.getBackground();
    navViewBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
        navViewBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
            .build());
```

In this way the `NavigationView` has rounded corners.
Now you have to pay attention to the header layout to build a rounded corner on the top. You have to use as background for the header view, something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar" 
    ...>
```

where the side_nav_bar is

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
     ....
     <corners android:topRightRadius="32dp" />
</shape>
```

Don't use a rounded corner on the bottom, because it is only the view used on the header of the NavigationView.

[image]

The `ShapeAppearanceModel` requires the version 1.1.0 of material components (currently `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'`)

Answer (score 3):

You can just add this line into `NavigationView`:

```
app:drawerLayoutCornerSize="xdp"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin Language create a class to make extensions:

```
fun MaterialNavigationView.changeCornerRadius() {
    val navViewBackground : MaterialShapeDrawable = background as MaterialShapeDrawable
    val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.menu_radius)
    navViewBackground.shapeAppearanceModel = navViewBackground.shapeAppearanceModel
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
        .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
        .build()
}
```

Usage:

```
val materialNavigationView: MaterialNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.material_navigation_view)
materialNavigationView.changeCornerRadius()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bottom left radious

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<corners android:radius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: It can't work in this way because it is the background of the headerView, not of the entire navigationView.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MaterialShapeDrawable, the following method.
It's also the best way I think.

First, Adjust the Opacity of the background of the Navigation View.
Second, Round the layout inside the Navigation View.

❖ However, be careful with the background of the top and bottom views.

layout_gnb.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/NAVIGATION_VIEW"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LINEAR_LAYOUT_03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_right_corner_light_white_rectangle">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

rounded_right_corner_light_white_rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topRightRadius="30dp" 
             android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorLightWhite" />
</shape>
```