# How to create a hidden draggable pane with handle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, draggable

I want to implement a hidden draggable pane with handle from left to right.[image: example of hidden draggable pane]

I've searched for a solution but it seems that `Navigational Drawer` layout is not for my case(maybe I'm wrong). I have tried to customize `NavigationView` in order to have the rounded green rect as background but it didn't work.

I have found solutions that use `SlidingDrawer` class but it's deprecated.

So, it's possible to have exactly the custom hidden pane in the picture or should I only follow the guidelines of `Material Design` ?

Comment: Although, there are many possible ways to acheive what you want to do like using a [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector) but with the [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout), it's easy, see [this official example](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#basic) of `MotionLayout`, that's exactly what you want and you just have to set the Constraints of Start and Ending Position in the `MotionScene` `xml`file, it will figure out the rest.

Comment: With the Material Components Library you can have a NavigationView with rounded corner. Check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929778/android-navigationview-vith-rounded-corners/57930457#57930457. In general you can apply it to every views.