# Is it possible to blur the DrawerLayout background color like a photo?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am designing a custom Drawer on Android, it must have rounded corners in top and bottom, I am first customizing top side and I find the problem that the background of the shape is not transparent.

I have:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y8jC.png)

I need to build: plus background blur
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbCv2.png)

I used this code to give a corner, but after using DrawerLayout -> BlurDrawerLayout it doesn't work.

my code:

```
var navViewBackground = navi.background as MaterialShapeDrawable
       navViewBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
                navViewBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius.toInt())
                    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius.toInt())
                    .build());
```

I tried blur using the BlurDrawerLayout library.

https://github.com/BALUSANGEM/BlurDrawerLayout

It's okay to suggest a better way.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57930457/12679944).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But it was the page I had already read.